# How to compose a query that matches multiple tag values?

Tags: influxdb

I was wondering what the best way is to compose a WHERE clause that matches multiple values for a tag. I was in the impression that i could solve this using a regex pattern but i seem to hit a wall. There is too many data returned in my query…

In my case i have several measurements that have an ‘location_id’ tag.

When i create a query using a where clause like below i get data back that is not correct. Probably to my misunderstanding on how to use the regex pattern or maybe it is impossible…

My data is as follows

```
time                 cpu  location_id
----                 ---- -----------
2017-11-27T07:00:00Z 159  2
2017-11-27T15:00:00Z 154  27
2017-11-27T23:00:00Z 117  7
2017-11-28T07:00:00Z 160  7
2017-11-28T15:00:00Z 167  27
2017-11-28T23:00:00Z 170  27
```

When i execute a query i only want the locations back with the value of ‘7’.
But when i use a query like below the data from location_id 27 is also returned…

SELECT * FROM “measurement” WHERE location_id =~ /7/;

My goal is that i would like to indicate that the location_id should be in a list of values. Is this even possible with regex? Or should i use AND clauses?

SELECT * FROM “measurement” WHERE location_id =~ /7|2|104|45/;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with regex (albeit only with tags/fields that are strings). First, recall that the regex `/7/` matches the character `7` *anywhere* in the input text. Therefore both "7" and "27" match.

To constrain the match to cover the entire input text, wrap it in start-of-text `^` and end-of-text `$` markers. For example, the regex `/^7$/` will match *only* the string "7" and nothing else.

To match against multiple entire strings, use the regex or operator `|`. Remember however that it has a lower operator precedence than composition, meaning we have to wrap the subexpression in parentheses. For example, `/^(7|2|104|45)$/` will match against either "7", "2", "104", or "45".

See the [golang regex syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/) documentation for more details.

Comment: Works flawless! Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use variables with regex match, for example a list variable named "Variable" can be matched using the following expression.

/^($Variable$)$/